# File deleted as soon as uploaded

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web-hosting, softaculous

One of the Yii2 framework files (AssetManager.php) is removed as soon as uploaded on shared server (vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ or ANY location). Even the version downloaded with softaculous don't contain that file.

How to solve it ?

Comment: more information?.  may be some code regarding this.

Comment: Because I think code had nothing to do with this problem. I found a similar issue on github, and someone respond "The file was being removed automatically because of the calls to symlink()". But someone posted "The file was being removed automatically because of the calls to symlink()" but didn't understand what he means. How a new file can affect a symlink ???

Comment: just add the upload code pleas. then we see what going on.

Comment: The file is too big (about 1.000 lines). But I discover that a function symlink() call is the main problem. The file is kept by server when I deleted them.